# My navbar toggle does not collapse

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am trying to redo my personal page and I am having problems with the Navbar. when I first made it I didn't have one, now I am trying to add one and change the entire layout. I have the nabber up and everything is in place, now when the icons show up when the screen is small, it does not collapse. I followed the instructions with bootstrap and I am trying to be more proficient in it but I can't seem to find why it does not work. My code is in [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/IrvingG/pen/adqaXg?editors=1000)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#slide2">Home <span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide2">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide3">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#slide4">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: you need serial your srcipt cdn like this first jquery.js then bootstrap.min.js 
<script  src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine. The only thing that you did wrong was to include `Bootstrap` before `jQuery`.

[This](http://codepen.io/divyanshu013/pen/RGLBpa) is a working fork of your code in which I changed the order to include `jQuery` first. You can change the order by checking the settings of your pen where you've included external resources (CSS or JS).

Comment: thank you, that worked! 

I just remembered that order matters there.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Was Not Working , Try to add this from Jquery cdn at the End Of your code before Closing body :

```html
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"   integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Jquery does not works. Add these lines on the head of your html document:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    <script> $(function(){ $('.nav-tabs a:first').tab('show'); }); </script>
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it solves the problem.

Comment: Code only answers are considered low quality posts. Please add some explanation for your code